# Best way to observe list of objects reassigned every x seconds

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a list of objects in my viewmodel. The list is reassigned every 5 seconds with a list of objects returned from an API call. For most of the objects in the list, their properties remain the exact same. However, for some of the objects, their properties are changed. I need a way for compose to know which items in the list have different values for their properties, and only recompose those items. Is their a way to accomplish this with LiveData?

Comment: are those items in a recycler view?

Comment: @JustSightseeing the items are displayed in LazyColumn. Each item is in a composable that should observe the respective object in the list

Comment: I haven't really used compose that much yet, but I believe it will force a recomposition in the lazy column anyway, so updating only the chaged items isn't possible as far as I know (but I'm not sure about that)

Comment: If you ensure that your model objects are stable (either inferred by the compiler or via `@Stable` or `@Immutable` annotations), then Compose takes care of this for you. Conversely, in Compose, there is no concept of "make the changes in the UI for only those items", except for Compose's own change detection logic. This isn't the view system, where we actually change the UI -- Compose is declarative, so you say what the UI should look like based on the now-current data, and Compose will "make the changes in the UI for only those items" where it thinks the data changed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I should have been clearer - I want only the items that display the objects whose data has changed to be recomposed. How would I go about observing the state in the composable?

Comment: "I want only the items that display the objects whose data has changed to be recomposed" -- as I wrote, if you ensure that your model objects are stable (either inferred by the compiler or via `@Stable` or `@Immutable` annotations), then Compose takes care of this for you. Compose will detect which objects changed and will only recompose those portions where the objects changed.